# Javascript: How do you call a variable function inside a prototype class?

Tags: javascript, class, project, prototype

Okay so we have a project ongoing, and it is to be passed today. But I have a problem.
This is the sample code:

output.js

```
var MapPrintDialog = Class.create();
MapPrintDialog.prototype = {

    // 他の画面からテンプレート情報を更新するために呼ばれる。
comboReload : function() {
    var val = tempComb.getValue();
    tempComb.store.load({
        callback: function(result, o) {
            if (this.store.data.keys.indexOf(val) == -1) {
                this.setValue(this.store.data.keys[0]);
                this.fireEvent("select", this);
            }
        }.createDelegate(tempComb)
    });
},

initialize  :   function(){
    this.define();
},

define  :   function(){
    var DrawPrintAreaFrame = function(mode, noUpdateStatusBarText){
    var cs = getCurrentSetting();

        if (mode == "init" || mode == "edit"){     
            PrintController.DrawMapPrintArea(cs.center.x, cs.center.y, cs.scale, cs.result.PrintMaps[0].Width, cs.result.PrintMaps[0].Height, cs.result.PageRowCount, cs.result.PageColumnCount, mode);
        }
        else if (mode == "delete"){
            PrintFrameManager.ClearPrintFrame();
        }    

        if (noUpdateStatusBarText) {
            gisapp.noUpdateStatusBarText = true;
        }
        gisapp.refreshMap();
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, how will I call "DrawPrintAreaFrame" from another js file?

I tried:

```
MapPrintDialog.prototype.define().DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
MapPrintDialog.prototype.define.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
MapPrintDialog.define().DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
MapPrintDialog.define.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
MapPrintDialog.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
```

but it gives me an error lol. How will I fix this? Please don't be too harsh, I just started learning javascript but they gave me an advanced project which isn't really "beginner" friendly XD

EDIT ----------------------

Okay now i tried to modify it like this:

```
var MapPrintDialog = Class.create();
MapPrintDialog.prototype = {

    // 他の画面からテンプレート情報を更新するために呼ばれる。
comboReload : function() {
    var val = tempComb.getValue();
    tempComb.store.load({
        callback: function(result, o) {
            if (this.store.data.keys.indexOf(val) == -1) {
                this.setValue(this.store.data.keys[0]);
                this.fireEvent("select", this);
            }
        }.createDelegate(tempComb)
    });
},

initialize  :   function(){
    this.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
    }
}

function DrawPrintAreaFrame(mode, noUpdateStatusBarText){
  var cs = gisapp.getCurrentView();

  if (mode == "init" || mode == "edit"){     
      PrintController.DrawMapPrintArea(cs.center.x, cs.center.y, cs.scale, cs.result.PrintMaps[0].Width, cs.result.PrintMaps[0].Height, cs.result.PageRowCount, cs.result.PageColumnCount, mode);
  }
  else if (mode == "delete"){
      PrintFrameManager.ClearPrintFrame();
  }    

  if (noUpdateStatusBarText) {
      gisapp.noUpdateStatusBarText = true;
  }
  gisapp.refreshMap();
}
```

But it gives me: **Javascript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DrawPrintAreaFrame'**

Comment: You can't - not like that. You need to expose that function. Exactly how you do that depends on how you want to call it (e.g. which of your attempts you want to work).

Comment: @Matt oh okay.. what if I created a DrawPrintAreaFrame function outside the prototype, can I still call it inside that prototype? cause there is some part in the prototype where I needed to call the function I created.

Comment: Of course - just like you did with `initialize`/`define`.

Comment: Umm yes. trying it now, but can't make it work as of now lol >_< I wasn't the one who created this code. Only the DrawPrintAreaFrame. So Im kinda having a little probs.

Comment: that part where I have to create var obj, obj.define() etc. etc. The construction of codes that they created is sorta confusing. I don't know where to insert my codes TwT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different way:

**1-** you have to first change it like this:

```
define  :   function(){
    var DrawPrintAreaFrame = function(mode, noUpdateStatusBarText){
        //You function code
    }
    this.getDrawPrintAreaFrame = function(){
        return DrawPrintAreaFrame;
    }
}
```

then create your object using your class:

```
var obj = new MapPrintDialog();
obj.define();
obj.getDrawPrintAreaFrame().call(obj, "edit");
```

**2-** remove the define method and add your function to prototype:

```
MapPrintDialog.prototype.DrawPrintAreaFrame = function(){
    //your function code
}
```

create your object and simply call your method like this:

```
var obj = new MapPrintDialog();
obj.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
```

> It's funny, because I said you have 2 ways, and the third one just came up:

**3-** as far as you use `Prototype` framework you can use `MapPrintDialog.addMethods`, which is there to be used to add new instance methods to your class, remove your `define` and `DrawPrintAreaFrame` functions and add this:

```
MapPrintDialog.addMethods({
    DrawPrintAreaFrame: function DrawPrintAreaFrame(){
        //your code
    }
});
```

or even without removing your method you can use it like:

```
define  :   function(){
    var DrawPrintAreaFrame = function(mode, noUpdateStatusBarText){
        //You function code
    }
    MapPrintDialog.addMethods({ DrawPrintAreaFrame: DrawPrintAreaFrame });
}
```

and create your instance and call the method:

```
var obj = new MapPrintDialog();
obj.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
```

4- try this if you need your function like a sort of static method, without needing to create a instance:

```
MapPrintDialog.DrawPrintAreaFrame = function(){
    //You function code
}
```

and call it like this

```
MapPrintDialog.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");
```

and if you want to define it in runtime, add the whole definition to your define method like this:

```
define  :   function(){
    MapPrintDialog.DrawPrintAreaFrame = function(){
        //You function code
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, what is **var mode, noUpdateStatusBarText;** for? if I can just call it like **obj.getDrawPrintAreaFrame().call(obj, "edit");** without using the var mode etc.

Comment: thanks for reminding me it was extra, I removed them

Comment: I can't delete **define:** because there are methods and variables there that is being used by another js files. I just inserted my functions in there because there's a variable inside define that I needed in order to make my function work. It's really confusing XDD I don't know what to do, sorry ><

Comment: ohh.. okay, I'll try the third one. By the way. If I am inside the same js file where I created the DrawPrintAreaFrame function, do I still need to add **var obj = new MapPrintDialog();
obj.DrawPrintAreaFrame("edit");** or can I simply use **this.DrawPrintAreaFrame** or something because I have to call it inside **define** too

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addMethods' :/

Comment: if you don't need your class properties inside your DrawPrintAreaFrame function try my forth solution that I'm just adding.

Comment: OMG WOW! It's finally working! You save my life! I only have 16 minutes before deadline :D